# TwinCAT 3 using Union in function argument

Tags: function, union, twincat

I made union, which allow me to use same data as  REAL or 4 bytes (Module in profibus device has 4 BYTE registers to write REAL floating point type value).

```
The union:
TYPE U_4Bytes2Real :
UNION
    abDataBytes     :       ARRAY[0..3] OF BYTE;
    rDataFloat      :       REAL;
END_UNION
END_TYPE
```

When I want to get access to this variable like REAL, I write:

```
U_4Bytes2Real.rDataFloat
```

When I want to get access to this variable like 4 BYTE ARRAY, I write:

```
U_4Bytes2Real.abDataBytes
```

I want to have a function, which gets REAL value, and inside it, I want to write it to the registers as an ARRAY of BYTES.

How to tell my function, that argument is REAL?

I' using function like that:

```
bFunResult := F_SetMod22(bDataGroup := 3, bChannel := 3, bDataFloat := 20.0, nTimeout := 100);
```

and i get error

```
Cannot convert type 'LREAL' to type 'U_4Bytes2Real'
```

Do I have to convert it INTO function, or there is some method to use union in function argument?

Comment: Please, attach declaration and implementation of F_SetMod22

Comment: It is unclear where this type conversion error is being generated. Somewhere you are declaring a LREAL, could that be a REAL instead? Or use `LREAL_TO_REAL()`?

Comment: try using the MEMSET function inside your function, pass in the address of the REAL variable. To set the bytes, get address of the REAL value and cut 4 bytes, starting at address ADR(<real value>) and add 1 byte for each MEMSET operation - or just paste whole rral values memory values to the byte array address. Make sure you are writting to correct positions of memory or bad stuff can happen :S

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer

> UNION is a STRUCT with a shared dataspace

This means anything that you can do with a STRUCT, you can do with a UNION. Whether that is use for inputs/outputs to a method, function, function block.

```
VAR
   Data : U_4Bytes2Real;
END_VAR

 F_Function( RealValue := Data.rDataFloat );
```

---

#### Example

Very simplest program to demonstrate this principle. It doesn't matter whether you are using a UNION or a STRUCT, they are accessed exactly the same.

```
TYPE st_Struct :
STRUCT
    Value                       : REAL;
    Packed                      : ARRAY [ 0..3 ] OF BYTE;    
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

```
TYPE u_Union :
UNION
    Value                       : REAL;
    Packed                      : ARRAY[0..3] OF BYTE;
END_UNION
END_TYPE
```

```
FUNCTION f_Sum : REAL
VAR_INPUT
    A, B                        : REAL;
END_VAR 

f_Sum := A + B;
```

```
PROGRAM MAIN
VAR
    Str                         : st_Struct;
    Uni                         : u_Union;
    Result                      : REAL;
END_VAR

Result := f_Sum( Str.Value, Uni.Value );
```

Answer (score 0):

For this answer I assume from your incomplete information:

Declaration ***assumption***:

```
VAR
bFunResult : U_4Bytes2Real;


METHOD F_SetMod22 : LREAL
```

Then you can write:

```
bFunResult.rDataFloat = TO_REAL(F_SetMod22(...));
```

And later use:

```
bFunResult.abDataBytes
```

***BUT !!!:***
Be aware, that TO_REAL will cut off information if the returned LREAL does not fit into a REAL.

Answer (score 0):

Your question and description of the problem is really poor. But from what I understand, here is what I can provide regarding setting the array values from the real value.

Creating union data type:

```
TYPE UnionType :
UNION
    fReal       : REAL;
    arrBytes    : ARRAY[0..3] OF BYTE;
END_UNION
END_TYPE
```

Creating function which takes input REAL and returns ARRAY[0..3] of BYTE:

```
// What is the purpose of this function, what does it return? 
FUNCTION F_SetMod22 : ARRAY[0..3] OF BYTE;
VAR_INPUT
    fValueIn    : REAL;
END_VAR
VAR
    arrResult   : ARRAY[0..3] OF BYTE;
END_VAR

// Simply copy and paste the memory from the source address to the target address
MEMCPY(srcAddr := ADR(fValueIn), destAddr := ADR(arrResult[0]), n := SIZEOF(arrResult));
F_SetMod22 := arrResult;
```

Now calling the function in main. To the input we set the unions REAL value and we return the result to the array of the unions ARRAY value. To test the result, I will set a pointer to the union's ARRAY variable and set the value to a REAL test variable:

```
PROGRAM MAIN
VAR
    uniValues   : UnionType := (fReal := 30.0);
    fResultTest : REAL;
    pointerToReal   : POINTER TO REAL;
END_VAR

uniValues.arrBytes := F_SetMod22(fValueIn := uniValues.fReal);
pointerToReal := ADR(uniValues.arrBytes[0]);
fResultTest := pointerToReal^;
```

two examples:
Value 199.99 was passed to the function. The returned array is set, test result is 199.99 as well:
[image]
Negative values test now:
[image]

I hope this helps. If this is not what you need, please give more information on the problem.